# How to plot a stacked bar based on frequency of values in a pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, frequency, stacked-chart

I have a dataframe with two columns 'position' and 'rankvalue'.

```
rankvalue   position
    0   D   3
    1   D   20
    2   S   1
    3   D   80
    4   D   100
    5   S   1
    6   D   3
    7   D   100
    8   D   20
    9   D   80
    10  D   20
    11  D   80
    12  S   1
    13  D   3
    14  D   100
    15  S   1
    16  VS  3
    17  LS  100
    18  D   20
    19  LS  80
```

I grouped it by 'position' and then calculated the frequency of 'rankvalue' for each position:

```
aggre= results.groupby(['position','rankvalue'])['position'].agg({'Frequency':'count'})
```

This produces the percentage:

```
final = aggre.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x:100 * x / float(x.sum()))
```

[image]

How can I generate a stacked bar based on the dataframe 'final'?

```
final.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True) # this does not produce intended stacked bar
```

The x-axis should be position (1,3,20,80,100) and y-axis should be frequency percentage. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Post text data not images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
final.Frequency.unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Or

```
final.Frequency.unstack(0).plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Comment: "final.Frequency.unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)" is the correct answer..

Comment: @kitchenprinzessin feel free to upvote the answer as well if you found it useful.